# Parsing a text file (large dataset) in java

Tags: java, parsing, inputstream

I have a text file, each line looks like this :
(a movie reviews database)

```
product/productId: B00004CK40   review/userId: A39IIHQF18YGZA   review/profileName: C. A. M. Salas  review/helpfulness: 0/0 review/score: 4.0   review/time: 1175817600 review/summary: Reliable comedy review/text: Nice script, well acted comedy, and a young Nicolette Sheridan. Cusak is in top form.
```

I want to parse this file in order to retrieve :

- product/productId
- review/userId
- review/profileName
- review/helpfulness
- review/score
- review/time
- review/summary
- review/text

This information will be later encapsulated using `MovieReview` & `Movie` class.

```
public class MovieReview {

    private Movie movie;
    private String userId;
    private String profileName;
    private String helpfulness;
    private Date timestamp;
    private String summary;
    private String review;
...
```

Can anyone offer a proper & efficient way to parse this file (large dataset) ?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you handle occurrences of, say, the string "review/text:" in the text of the review? This is relevant for parsing. If it is not handled at all, your application may fail at any time if users get inventive.

Comment: I assume that "review/text:" won't occur on the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a large dataset, you'll want to avoid loading the entire list into memory at once. I'd probably solve this with a handler for each row

```
public interface MovieReviewHandler {
    void handle(MovieReview revies);
}
```

Then you could parse as follows:

```
public class MovieReviewParser {
    public void parse(BufferedReader reader, MovieReviewHandler handler) {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("product/productId:(.*)review/userId:(.*)review/profileName:(.*)"); // add other fields

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(line);
            if (!matcher.matches()) throw new RuntimeException();
            MovieReview review = new MovieReview();
            review.productId = matcher.group(1);
            review.userId = matcher.group(2);
            review.profileName = matcher.group(3);
            // etc

            handler.handle(review);
        }
    }
}
```